# IndexError for Shap TreeExplainer with Univariate IsolationForest

Tags: scikit-learn, index-error, anomaly-detection, shap, isolation-forest

Help! IndexError when trying to explain an IsolationForest.

I am using `Scikit-learn`'s `IsolationForest` for anomaly detection. Usually, the datasets I use have more than one variable - but sometimes they only have one. This works for fitting and predicting the model. However, for explaining the model's output using `shap`'s `TreeExplainer`, I get an `IndexError`.

**See below for a minimal reproducible example:**

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import IsolationForest
from shap import TreeExplainer

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Column1'] = np.random.randint(0, 100, 100)
model = IsolationForest()
model.fit(X=df)
explainer = TreeExplainer(model)
```

The root cause of the problem seems to be the following (see code below): each `IsolationForest` has multiple isolation trees. In the `TreeExplainer`, multiple `IsoTree` objects are initialised. During initialisation, this line crashes, because `self.features`, a list, contains -2, which is out of bounds since `tree_features` is just an array (`[0]`). So maybe the problem is that when fitting the `IsolationForest`, the wrong values are given for `self.features`.

```py
# re-number the features if each tree gets a different set of features
self.features = np.where(self.features >= 0, tree_features[self.features], self.features)
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Of course, for a univariate model, using Shapley values is pointless since you could just use the anomaly scores from `score_samples`. I plan to use this as a workaround, but surely there's a more elegant way where this would not be required?

Thanks and best wishes,

Alexander

Comment: Please [reprex]

Comment: Thank you Sergey, I have a minimal reproducible example so I'll add that now (see original post)